# SQL Query - FindCostumerWithHighestBill

Tags: java, sql, subquery

I am try to find the costumer with the highest bill   using this sql that I wrote  , but apparently I run into this error :

```
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

This is what I wrote:

```
public static void findCustomerWithHighestBill(Connection c) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, CITY, sum(sum_all) As 'data'\r\n"
            + "FROM (SELECT *, sum(Price) As 'sum_all'\r\n"
            + "     FROM (SELECT *, Customer.NAME AS \"CustomerName\"\r\n"
            + "         FROM Transactions\r\n"
            + "         INNER JOIN Product ON Product.ID = Transactions.ProductID\r\n"
            + "         INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.ID = Transactions.CustomerID)\r\n"
            + "     GROUP BY CustomerID, ProductID\r\n"
            + " ) \r\n"
            + "GROUP BY CustomerID\r\n"
            + "ORDER BY data DESC";
    Statement statement = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery(query);
    set.next();
    System.out.println("CustomerID: " + set.getInt("CustomerID") +
            ", Name: " + set.getString("CustomerName") + ", City: " +
            set.getString("CITY") + ", Bill: " + set.getFloat("data"));
}
```

Can  please somoane help me zith this ?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...) some_alias` - just add it

Comment: you need alias for subqueries

Comment: HeySorry  @PM77-1, I cannot  find  out where to make the change,  can you be  more precised please ?

Comment: I showed the exact spot: right after the closing bracket.

Comment: Look carefully.  You have this issue twice (two derived tables).  So you'll need to provide two aliases, one for each.  `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM (...) AS t2 ...) AS t1 ...`

Comment: indeed  @JonArmstrong , I did not realize that  since I  am pretty new in this  , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Coming back ,
It seems that indeed ad most of you says in the comments I should identify my  tables first  but, apparently I also have miss to avoid the duplicate ID column.
Here goes my new query:

```
   String query = "SELECT CID, CustomerName, City, sum(sum_all) As data" +
                "                FROM (SELECT *, sum(PPROD) As sum_all" +
                "               FROM (SELECT Product.ID as PID,Customer.ID as CID,Product.Price as PPROD,City, Customer.NAME AS CustomerName" +
                "              FROM Transactions" +
                "               INNER JOIN Product ON Product.ID = Transactions.ProductID" +
                "                INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.ID = Transactions.CustomerID) As t2" +
                "               GROUP BY CID, PID" +
                "               ) As t1" +
                "               GROUP BY CID" +
                "              ORDER BY data DESC;";
```